# how to add button in required cell in table layout panel windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm fresher. I have a windows application with a table layout panel. When I drag and drop a button in my required cell, it is inserting the button into a different cell. Which property do I need to set to add the button in my required cell.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that in each 'cell' you can only have one control. Also. do re-read your post and add a few spaces and line breaks etc.. Also: your description is not really clear and helpful..

Comment: In that cell no control there

Comment: Each cell can only have one thing in it. If your button is placed in a different cell this means something else was already in the cell you dropped it on. Also TableLayoutPanel has no concept of required cell. What is your intention there?

Comment: We are talking about placing a control in the designer, right? Or at runtime?? The designer should show a 'forbidden' sign when you try to drop a control on an occupiod cell and not drop it at all until you click on an empty cell. - If you are doing it at runtime do show the code!!

Comment: Yes design time.when i drag and drop the button in different column cell to my required column cell it is not taking.It going another column cell

Comment: Do double-check that cell. I bet there is something tiny inside it, maybe a Label without text? What happens when you simply click that cell? Nothing or a 'forbidden' sign flash..?

Comment: This should help: `foreach (Control ctl in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
                Console.WriteLine(ctl.Name + " in " + tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumn(ctl) + 
                                  " / " + tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(ctl));` If it doesn't delete the TLP and add a fresh one!

Comment: I tried drag and drop, Insert the button control to the specified tabellayoutPanel cell. Could you please check this as a small application?compare that to your mainproject if any property values are differ from small application.